# Como correr una aplicacion desarrollada para android 4.2.1 en versiones 5.0.1 en adelante

Tags: android, app

Desarrolle una aplicación para Android sin problemas en 4.2.1 y corre bien. El problema surge cuando trato de ejecutar la aplicación en versiones nuevas, la app se cierra. Estuve leyendo acerca de la compatibilidad de las versiones en Android y encontré que necesito descargar las librerías para las versiones mas actualizadas. La pregunta es, ¿Necesito agregar algo al código o en el AndroidManifest.xml?

Muchas gracias, por adelantado.

Comment: You must post your question in http://stackoverflow.com/. This page is in spanish.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque está en inglés y no está relacionada con SOes

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés.

Comment: Tienes acceso al LogCat? que error obtienes? @ArtEze ya esta en espanol!